# Vaadin : My label ignores the carriage return character

Tags: label, vaadin

I have an incoming text string that contains a line break ("\r").

When I output it with : `System.out.println(myString)`, the carriage return is interpreted.

However, when I set the string as the Label's content, it ignores the carriage return.

How can I force the Label to interpret the carriage/line return (without the XHTML mode) ?

Answer (score 7):

This is how you can put this text into your label:

```
@Override
public void init() {
    Window window = new Window();
    Label label = new Label("<pre>First line\rSecond line\nThird line</pre>", Label.CONTENT_XHTML);
    window.addComponent(label);
    setMainWindow(window);
}
```

The key is using Label.CONTENT_XHTML content mode and enclosing the text inside a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: `Label.CONTENT_XHTML` - **Deprecated.** As of 7.0, use `ContentMode.HTML` instead

Answer (score 3):

In Vaadin 7.0 you can use ContentMode.PREFORMATTED e.g.:

```
String resultText = "First line\rSecond line\nThird line";
Label dateLabel = new Label( resultText, ContentMode.PREFORMATTED );
```

and if you want text to look sexy you can use some themes, something like:

```
dateLabel.setStyleName( Runo.LABEL_SMALL );
```

That should work and is elegant as well.

Answer (score 0):

After reading The book of Vaadin, and few tests, I don't think \r can be interpreted by the Label.

Replacing  \r with \n  gives you two options :

```
Label.setContentMode(Label.CONTENT_XHTML). //But you don't want to do this
Label.setContentMode(Label.CONTENT_PREFORMATTED) //But I think it's not the display you want
```

Regards.

Éric